# Mono cannot find LibVLC or MPV on NixOS

Tags: libraries, nixos, vlc, mono, .net

I am trying to use SubtitleEdit, a .NET application, on NixOS, using Mono. This has worked in the past with other distros, but for some reason SubtitleEdit cannot find mpv or libvlc on NixOS. Everything is installed via configuration.nix, so I suspect I somehow need to expose LibVLC or mpv to Mono and thus SubtitleEdit. How can I do this?

Note: Installing the LibVLC package breaks VLC for some reason, and SubtitleEdit defaults to and works better with LibMPV anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some loosely correct info found on ChatGPT, I found that libmpv.so existed at /run/current-system/sw/lib/ once mpv was installed, and then I discovered that setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable with either `env` or `export` to include that path, like so,...
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/run/current-system/sw/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`
...before running `mono subtitleEdit.exe`, fixed the problem, TYJ!